# How to send numberInput as a parameter? Or how I can receive numberInput box inside a loop data from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to build up a Point of sale. But I can't receive the quantity from a numberInput box. All other's is okay. Plz help me in this regard.I have tried by using Html.BeginForm(). But in case of quantity it's showing null.

I'have tried with html.BegingForm. But as the NumberInputBox is inside a loop the controller action method getting null values.

Here is my View code from where I'm trying to send the number,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <table class="table">

        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductCode)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SellingPrice)
            </th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>


        @foreach (var item in Model)


        {
            <tbody id="myTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellingPrice)
                    </td>

                    <td>

                        **<input type="number" class="numberInput" name="SaleQuantity" id="SaleQuantity" min="1">**

                    <td>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("GetProductInReceipt", "Sale", new { id = item.ProductId })">+</a>

                    </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        }


    </table>

}
```

And below is my controller code, in where I'm trying to get it

```
public ActionResult GetProductInReceipt(int id, int **SaleQuantity**)
{

    ProductSale productSale = db.ProductSales.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProductId == id);
    Product product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProductId == id);

    List<ProductSale> ProductSales = (List<ProductSale>)Session["ProductSale"];
    if (ProductSales == null)
    {
        ProductSales = new List<ProductSale>();
    }

    ProductSales.Add
    (
        new ProductSale()
        {
            ProductId = product.ProductId,
            SaleId = (db.Sales.Max(a => a.SaleId))+1,
            SalePrice = product.SellingPrice,
            SaleQuantity = **SaleQuantity**,
            TotalPrice = SaleQuantity * product.SellingPrice,
            Product = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProductId == product.ProductId)
        }
    );
    Session["ProductSale"] = ProductSales;}
```

But in sale quantity is getting null.

Comment: If you are using @using(Html.BeginForm()) then it should contain a Submit button to submit the data. And also pass the ViewModel Name in parameter.

Comment: I think you can use ajax for this. If you want, I can post a sample.

Comment: Unfortunately, no ajax call is working on my project. I'm trying to fix it. Once I'm done with fixing I'll use ajax. Please,  post your sample. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use ajax you can simply send both of the parameters together. Please try this one.

In your view

```
<div>
       @{ var i = 0;}

                        <tbody id="myTable">
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SellingPrice)
                                    </td>


                                    <td>

                                        <input type="number" value="1" class="numberInput" name="SaleQuantity@(i)" id="SaleQuantity@(i)" min="1">


                                    </td>


                                    <td>
                                        <input type="button" value="+" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetProductInReceipt", "Sale")?qty=' + document.getElementById('SaleQuantity@(i)').value + '&productId=@item.ProductId'" />

                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                i++;
                            }
                        </tbody>
```

And in your Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetProductInReceipt(string qty,int productId)                 
{
    // Handle as per your software
}
```